# In testcode, Spring can't qualify interface when using @MockBean

Tags: spring-boot, testing, proxy, mockito

Therse is @Component that implements two interface.

```java
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class MemberPersistenceAdapter implements LoadMemberPort, UpdateMemberPort {...}
```

In test code, when I apply @MockBean to a interface of Spring Bean that implements both interfaces, it doesn't qualify the another interface.

```java
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class LoginServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    JwtProvider mailJwtProvider;

    @Autowired
    LoginService loginService;

    @MockBean
    LoadMemberPort loadMemberPort;

    @Test
    void givenValidToken_whenLogin_thenReturnAuthToken() {
        String mail = "test@test.com";
        String token = mailJwtProvider.createJwtToken(mail);

        when(loadMemberPort.isRegisteredMail(anyString()))
                .thenReturn(true);
        LoginUseCase.AuthToken authToken = loginService.login(token);

        assertThat(authToken.getAccessToken()).isNotBlank();
        assertThat(authToken.getRefreshToken()).isNotBlank();
    }
}
```

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No qualifying bean of type '...UpdateMemberPort' available: 
expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

So I apply @MockBean to `UpdateMemberPort`.
Then test passes.
If Mockito make Proxy `LoadMemberPort`, then `MemberPersistenceAdapter` is disappear?

```java
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class LoginServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    JwtProvider mailJwtProvider;

    @Autowired
    LoginService loginService;

    @MockBean
    LoadMemberPort loadMemberPort;

    @MockBean
    UpdateMemberPort updateMemberPort;

    @Test
    void givenValidToken_whenLogin_thenReturnAuthToken() {
        String mail = "test@test.com";
        String token = mailJwtProvider.createJwtToken(mail);

        when(loadMemberPort.isRegisteredMail(anyString()))
                .thenReturn(true);
        LoginUseCase.AuthToken authToken = loginService.login(token);

        assertThat(authToken.getAccessToken()).isNotBlank();
        assertThat(authToken.getRefreshToken()).isNotBlank();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why Spring context can't find `MemberPersistenceAdapter`?

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you create a mockbean for an interface, you will get a mockbean for this interface and this interface only. You won't get a mockbean for a different interface. If your actual code depends on both interfaces, you need to have (mock)beans for both interfaces. Where are your beans used in the real code?